# How to stop background-position making the background image less sharp?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background, background-image

I have a 1920x1080 JPEG background image that I am using on a 1920x1080 screen.

It has the following properties:

```
background-image: url(/bg.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: repeat;
```

In Chrome, **without** the `background-position: center top;` the background is perfectly scaled and sharp. With this property added, the background loses sharpness.

Weirdly, if the browser width is an odd number, the image is perfectly sharp. So 1920x1080 would be a bit blurry, but 1919x1080 would be perfect.

In Edge and Firefox, the background image is perfectly scaled in either case.

The `background-position` property is required for proper positioning due to scroll bars on some browsers.

I have tried `image-rendering`. The only property that I could actually see a difference with was `pixelate`, but it caused tearing at some parts.

I have trialed lots of different property combinations (`background-size`), but I definitely could've missed something.

My question is the title:

> How to stop background-position making the background image less sharp?

But the answer to this question would also resolve my problem, as I think that this might be a bug or at least an after-effect/result of one of Chrome's features:

> How to stop Chrome resizing (or doing something else) to a background image when it is being positioned?

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple reasons why this is happening.

I'd take a guess and say that the background-size isn't being set. I would be tempted the have this set to `background-size: contain` to keep your ratio in tack. Also when you are using `background-attachment: fixed;` make sure the div is `position: static`.

Hope this help, if not, supply a jsfiddle and I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response mate! Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sr4qkt6f/11/
Unfortunately, those recommendations didn't work (or at least I didn't implement them correctly). The background needs to maintain its size, `contain` would resize to fit the screen.

Comment: If you look at the text (on the right side of the image) with the `background-position` property, then remove the `background-position` property and look again, you'll see what I mean about the sharpness. It's a little hard to notice but it should be clear enough.

Comment: No probs. I can see what you mean. It's due to the sub-pixel rendering on Chrome. try adding `image-rendering: pixelated;` It should round the image to the nearest pixel make it nice and crisp again.

Comment: Thanks! That causes tearing in the actual image we're using on our end. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Just looking for some more info, it does seem to be an issue with chrome when scaling images down. Perhaps using another `image-rendering` property might work maybe `-webkit-optimize-contrast`. Else the only other thing I can suggest is forcing the browser to use its GPU for rendering with `transform-style: preserve-3d;`

Answer (score 1):

```
image-rendering: pixelated;
```

it works for me.